# How to get .json file in folder structure

Tags: javascript, json

A pretty simple question here.

My project is set up like this:

```
dist
  - js
    - app.js
  - profile
    - profile.html
    - tab1.json
```

The script below is looking for the .json file in the js folder but I need it to be kept in the profile folder and just want to amend the JavaScript below:

```
var jsonFile='tab'+(tabIndex +1)+'.json'
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling javascript **what** your file is called, but not **where** it is. This is useless unless the file is in the same folder as the script (or the webpage). You have to fix this by adding the folder location to your variable.

If it's currently looking in the 'js' folder, then you must prepend the 'profile' directory so it will actually look there instead.

```
var jsonFile = '../profile/tab' + (tabIndex + 1) + '.json';
```

Comment: If the code is in `app.js` doesn't it need to be `../profile'`?

Comment: My mistake, didn't check the structure properly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using nodejs, the path module is your friend.: http://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Example: path.join('/foo', 'bar', 'baz/asdf', 'quux', '..')

I would imagine you need something like this.

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "profile", "tab" + (tabIndex +1) + ".json");
```

Your question does lack a few details so I've had to make a few assumptions, like you are using nodejs. Please do supply more information in future.

If you're working in the browser you will have to use a XHR.